# What did I do wrong? Why isn't Ubuntu loading?

Tags: dual-boot, wubi, windows-8, uefi

Something went wrong when I installed Ubuntu onto my Dell Inspiron laptop, preloaded with Windows 8. I installed Ubuntu 12.10 with Wubi, and then restarted my computer. When it restarted, I got an error message that said "Windows failed to start." It said that the some of the files were missing, and gave me error code 0xc0007b. I tried turning off the UEFI and Secure Boot thing that Windows 8 has, and I don't know where to go from here. Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: Here is the error message: Windows failed to start. File: \ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mdr Status: 0xc000007b The operating system failed to start because a required file is missing or contains errors. Any ideas?

Comment: After turning off UEFI, in most cases windows 8 needs to be reinstalled. Did you turned off UEFI, then boot windows 8 and the installed ubuntu? Also ubuntu 32bit doesn't recognize efi. Try with 64 bit if not. This might help you [Installing Ubuntu on a Pre-Installed UEFI Supported Windows 8 system](http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system). As of now, try to restore using windows 8 recovery

Comment: Wubi doesn't work with `UEFI` or `GPT` disks. Turning off `UEFI` wont' help without a full reinstall (including reformatting the entire disk so it has a `MBR` partition). It's much easier to do a normal dual boot with the 64-bit Ubuntu as mentioned. Switching back to `UEFI` boot should get Windows booting again, then just uninstall Wubi.

Answer (score 0):

You could hook up a windows 8 CD, and set to run and click repair. that might fix it